# Invalid index 0, size is 0 (Android)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Hola trato de llenar un Arraylist en un Fragment con datos de una tabla Sqlite (la tabla ya tiene datos) y me muestra el error del titulo en el catch.

**Clase InicioFragment**

```
public class InicioFragment extends Fragment {
    public RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    public RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    public SearchView searchView;
    public Context context;
    public ArrayList<InicioItem> arrayList;
    UtilidadesSQLite inicio;
    public List<UtilidadesSQLite > listCreditos;
    private conexion con;
    SQLiteDatabase bd;
    String id;

    public InicioFragment() { }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container, false);


        id=getArguments().getString("id");
        inicio= new UtilidadesSQLite ();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rclvInicio);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        searchView = (SearchView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.searchInicio);
        this.context = this.getContext();
        arrayList = new ArrayList<InicioItem>();

        listCreditos=new ArrayList<Inicio>();
        arrayList=GetArrayListInicioItem();
        adapter = new InicioRecyclerAdapter(context, arrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        return rootView;
    }

    public ArrayList<InicioItem> GetArrayListInicioItem(){
        con = new conexion(getActivity(), "bd_C", null, 1);
        bd=con.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            String query="Select * from " + Inicio.TInicio +" where Id= '"+id+"'";

            Cursor cursor = bd.rawQuery(query, null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst() == true) {
                    do {
                        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
                            inicio = listCreditos.get(i);
                            arrayList.add(new InicioItem(inicio));
                        }
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.toString();//Error aqui
        }
        bd.close();
        return arrayList;
    }
```

**Clase InicioItem**

```
public class InicioItem {

    public InicioItem(UtilidadesSQLite inicio) {
        this._inicio = inicio;
    }

    private UtilidadesSQLite _inicio;

    public UtilidadesSQLite inicio(){
        return _inicio;
    }

    public int imgBackground(){
        int imgbackground = R.drawable.background_item_red;
        if(_inicio != null){
            switch (Integer.parseInt(_inicio.Estatus)){
            case 0: 
                imgbackground =  R.drawable.background_item_red;
                break;
            case 1: 
                imgbackground =  R.drawable.background_item_teal;
                break;
            case 2: 
                imgbackground =  R.drawable.background_item_blue;
                break;
            }
        }
        return imgbackground;
    }

    public int img(){
        int img = R.drawable.ic_item_no_asignado;
        try{  
            if(_inicio != null){
                switch (Integer.parseInt(_inicio.Estatus)){
                case 0: 
                    img =  R.drawable.ic_item_no_asignado;
                    break;
                case 1: 
                    img =  R.drawable.ic_item_activo;
                    break;
                case 2: 
                    img =  R.drawable.ic_item_convenio_promesa_pago;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return img;
    }

    public String nombre(){
        if(_inicio != null)
        return _inicio.Nombre.toUpperCase();
        return "No hay registro";
    }
}
```

Gracias!

Comment: ¿En qué línea es el error?  ¿Podrías explicar lo que intentas hacer aquí: `inicio = listCreditos.get(i);`?  Me parece que `listCreditos` no tiene nada, no sé por qué haces eso ahí.

Comment: Hola lo que trato de hacer ahi es pasar los datos de la consulta a ese array listCreditos y luego enviarlo al arraylist

Comment: Tu código es algo confuso y mucho más al no respetar la *convención de nombres*. Lo que debes leer es el `cursor` y meter los valores de cada columna en el array. No se entiende bien el código, no se sabe si tienes una clase en la que mapeas cada columna de tu tabla. El principio es sencillo: leer los resultados (`cursor`)  y meter cada columna en el array (o mapearlo directamente desde una clase, si la tuvieras, que represente cada columna de tu tabla). Parece que con el `get(i)` quieres hacer eso, pero `listCreditos` no es tu conjunto de datos, no es otra cosa que un objeto vacío.

Comment: mmm podrias orientarme a como hacerlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si revisas tu código, estas creando un `ArrayList`

```
listCreditos=new ArrayList<Inicio>();
```

pero posteriormente estas tratando de obtener un elemento de este ArrayList, obviamente no contiene valores por eso el error:

```
 inicio = listCreditos.get(i);
```

---

En realidad veo un mal diseño en tu aplicación, primeramente debes obtener los objetos UtilidadesSQLite (inicio) para agregarlos a `listCreditos`, por lo pronto puedes comentar esta linea:

```
                    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
                        //inicio = listCreditos.get(i);
                        arrayList.add(new InicioItem(inicio));
                    }
```